# Starting multiple "TASK"s as async in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, parallels

I have two simple async methods.

```
static async Task First()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine($"First method: {i}");
    }
}

static async Task Second()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        Console.WriteLine($"Second method: {i}");
    }
}
```

And try to call them in a different manner and results are completely different. I show you every calling and its response message bellow.

1. Firstly await both simply.

   ```
        await First();
        await Second();

        //First method: 0
        //First method: 1
        //Second method: 0
        //Second method: 1
   ```
2. Secondly, create an array of tasks and call them by iterating. But the result is parallel.

   ```
      var tasks = new Task[] { First(), Second() };
      foreach (var t in tasks)
      {
          await Task.Run(async () => await t);
      }

      //Second method: 0
      //First method: 0
      //Second method: 1
      //First method: 1
   ```
3. The third example I call them as Parallel and its result is expected

```
          var tasks = new Task[] { First(), Second() };
          Parallel.ForEach(tasks, async (t) => { await Task.Run(async () => await t); });

          //First method: 0
          //Second method: 0
          //Second method: 1
          //First method: 1
```

4. And in the final example, I start Tasks at once. And result also as expected here.

   ```
        var tasks = new Task[] { First(), Second() };
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        //First method: 0
        //Second method: 0
        //Second method: 1
        //First method: 1
   ```

So my question: What is the difference between these 4 methods of calling async Tasks? Which of them is the best way to use?

Comment: _"Which of them is the best way to use?"_ What is your definition of "best"? 1 and 4 at least do not create unnecessary threads and mix concepts that do not particularly "like" each other. Now it depends on what you need. 1 will execute them in sequence ( `Second()` will execute after `First()` has finished), 4 will execute both asynchronously (which is _not_ equivalent to "in parallel") and await both to finish.

Comment: I mean performance when I say "Best". What about 2nd and 3rd examples?  Why 2nd example does not work like in the 1st? Why the second iteration does not await the first iterated and awaited Task?

Comment: Ok, #2: You start both tasks asynchonously. That means they may (or may not) execute on two threads in parallel (not guaranteed). Then you create and await two more tasks, that await their execution in sequence. So, here execution is separated from the order in which they are awaited. In the first snippet, you execute `First()` _and await it immediately_. That means it may or may not execute on a separate Thread but anyway, `Second()` will only be started _after_ `First()` has finished. So here the order of execution is the order in which they are awaited.

Comment: To asses, which performs better, I'd highly advise to do a benchmark (see Benchmark.NET). Mind that #4 only makes sense if `Second` does not depend on results from `First`. How #1 or #4 perform may depend on the implementations of `First` and `Second`, on load, on what is executing beside your app on the machine, ... so it may be hard to predict.

Comment: 1, 4 - good. 2,3 - bad. Refer to: [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) and [Why 3 is bad](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/psychic-debugging-of-async-methods/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results you are getting can be explained by the following

1. Your methods run sequentially, believe it or not `await` actually means *await* (Since there are no other tasks involved and your methods are not running unobserved)
2. Your tasks start as soon as you add them to the array, then you offload the work to another task and await that, however you run the workload as an `async void` which in-turn runs unobserved, as such each outer task returns immediately. The order of results depends on the task scheduler and a race between what would most likely be 2 threads.
3. You are are using a TPL method to potentially start tasks to start tasks which runs your workload as an `async void` and unobserved, as such the `Parallel.Foreach` returns immediately. The order of results depends on the task scheduler and a race between what would most likely be 2 threads.
4. You are starting 2 tasks and `await` the completion of them both. The order of results depends on the task scheduler and a race between what would most likely be 2 threads.

> Which of them is the best way to use?

This entirely depends on what you want to achieve... As they all do slightly different things for different reasons, and some have completely redundant aspects there is no right answer.

However, for your example methods `Task.WhenAll` seems to be the most succinct and sane approach if you want to wait for 2 `async` workloads to finish asynchronously

```
var tasks = new Task[] { First(), Second() };
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Regarding the explanation of 2, there is no `async void` involved. The `Task.Run` understands async delegates.